# Is anything wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I know the voting is a little shy on CR, but I'd have thought this post would have generated more views/votes at least a couple *comments*. But there's almost 60 views now, and still nothing.

[List<T> implementation for VB6/VBA](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32618/type-safe-list-implementation-for-vb6-vba)

Is there anything wrong with this question? If I were to review this code, I'd say something like it's generally clean and self-explanatory (maybe comments even clutter it up?), naming is good and consistent, and every function/method is very focused and that's good, **but** *xyz*.

Maybe this part is making the review request too narrow? Or the code is too trivial?

> I'd like to know if the implementation could be made better /more efficient, especially with Insert and Sort methods; also I'd like another pair of eyes to examine the errors being raised and see if it all makes sense - the idea isn't to throw every error that's possible to get with a List, but I might have missed throwing an error that could help usability.

Or maybe I'm just too eager to read a review of that code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 26 [vba](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba) and only 8 [vb6](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vb6) questions on this site (compared with over 1600 for the most popular tag, [c#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23)). I think this means there simply aren't many people interested in these languages on this site, which is why you didn't get any answers yet.

You might try to be patient, but I wouldn't be surprised if you didn't get any answers anytime soon. You could try a bounty, but it's hard to say if that would help.

And I agree with Malachi that the length doesn't help. You are free to post as much code as you want, but keep in mind that too much code can discourage people from looking at it (it certainly sometimes does for me).

Comment: Thanks! I've retagged with [tag:C#] since someone with knowledge of `List<T>` can probably give the best review here. I'll wait a bit more to see what I get out of it before I decide whether or not to put a bounty on it :)

Answer (score 5):

There is a lot of code in that question, and then there is even more code behind the links.  That one link you have has about 4 pages of code and explanation.

I would think that you would at least have some people marking it as a favorite so that they can come back to it later or something.

Maybe there are people who would like to review the code, but don't have the time to look at all of it at the moment, and forget to come back to it when they have more time.

I would probably chop it into smaller pieces, and separate it into more questions.

Comment: Lots of code indeed, but all functions range between very small and tiny. Still I broke the monolithic code block into multiple ones. The idea was that putting it all in a single code block made it easier to copy+pase, but I didn't realise the helper functions would have to be copied as well - and in the case of `StringFormat` it's quite a lot of code to copy over. I edited the last part to mention the linked stuff is there *only if you're interested in seeing the actual code* for these helper functions, and that the review isn't about those.